# Split duply/duplicity backup into subdirectories

Tags: duplicity, duply

I have been running backups with duply for a while now. This works great so far, but recently I started getting the error message `Attempt 1 failed. BackendException: Bad status code 507 reason Insufficient Storage`.

I still have enough storage available, but the storage service I use for backup has a limit of 3000 files per directory. Is there a way to tell duply/duplicity to automatically distribute the backup volumes over multiple directories?

Answer (score 0):

you can try the [multibackend](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html#sect18), which is normally meant to combine various different backends, but you should be able to point it to different folders on the same backend as well.

..ede/duply.net